# Name of lines drawn to indicate movement?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

This is a bit of a cryptic one; I was wondering whether English has a word (or at least a phrase) to describe the lines typically drawn on a cartoon to indicate movement?  A good example is the Windows XP 'Run' icon (in the top-left):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gesture lines can be used to indicate gestures, so I think that is a reasonable answer.  I've seen [motion lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_lines) more commonly used for the example that you have given.

Comment: Mort Walker called them "hites" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lexicon_of_Comicana

Comment: @JasonS That's a well-sourced answer. You ought to post it as such.

Comment: well maybe, but it's a Mort-Walker-ism, crafted somewhat in jest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a good answer for you, but I've seen similar things referred to as *gesture lines*.

[From Answers.com](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_gesture_line):

> Gesture lines are lines that are energetic and catch the movements and gestures of an active figure.

Read more: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_gesture_line#ixzz1O1t4BWRg

Answer (score 1):

The word is called 'emanata' but only used in comic books though.

Comment: We're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Actually, according to *[Quimps, Plewds, And Grawlixes: The Secret Language Of Comic Strips](https://www.fastcodesign.com/1673017/quimps-plewds-and-grawlixes-the-secret-language-of-comic-strips):  "Walker coins some more great terminologies. For example, any line used to show something moving is called a sphericasia."*

Answer (score 0):

These lines are called "movement lines" which is explained among other (comic related) techniques [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2311267_draw-showing-movement.html)

Comment: I've also heard them called "zoom lines".